# how to add unit id for admob after uploading the app to google play?

Tags: android-studio, admob

I have some apps which I did ready as apk file and I need to add admob unit id in it, the question is when I export the apk file without the unit id and upload it to google play... so after the uploading process do I have to go back and edit the android studio project again and do the export one more time with the unit id, how does this work?
google will give me the id after the uploading so how can I do this process the right way?
Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to the Ad Unit ID to display ads in your application?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the Ad Unit ID in your project and submit an update to the Google Play Store.

For the future, you **do not** need to have your application available on the Google Play Store before you can receive an Ad Unit ID.

To receive an Ad Unit ID for your application:

1. Go to AdMob.com> Monetize> Monetize New App.
2. Select "Add your app manually"> Fill out the required information.
3. Create an ad type> Use the Ad Unit ID it provides.

Once your application has been on the Google Play Store for a few days you will be able to link the Ad Unit ID to the application:

1. AdMob.com> Home> Find the app you added manually
2. Select "Link your app"> Search for the app> Select the app.